# Jackson Databind Deserializtion of Generic Enum

Tags: java, enums, json-deserialization, jackson-databind, json-serialization

I am trying to properly save/load data containing a generic enum. Currently the object contains a java.lang.Class object (clazz) that get serialized into the field "enumclass". The "al" field contains the value of the enum. My goal is to create a custom Jackson deserializer that uses the "val" field and the "enumclass" field to then run `Enum.valueOf()` to create an instance of the Enum.

However, when I run the deserializer, it throws a `JsonMappingException` and says `Cannot construct instance of 'java.lang.Class', problem: me.ExampleProject.Enums$RevealType$1`

I can't seem to get past this one issue and am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Example JSON:

```
"revealType": {
    "type": "enumspec",
    "id": "Reveal Type",
    "val": "SKIRT",
    "enumclass": "me.ExampleProject.Enums.RevealType",
    "ro": false,
    "sec": "Miscellaneous"
}
```

Deserialization Code:

```
Class clazz = MAP.convertValue(jsonNode.get("enumclass"), new TypeReference<Class<? extends Enum<?>>>() {});
Enum<?> value = Enum.valueOf(clazz, jsonNode.get("val").asText());
```

Comment: Read the `enumclass` as a String, then use `Class.forName`.

Comment: @Jorn after trying this solution, I am greeted with a ClassNotFoundException. This leads me to believe the issue has to do with the Classloader instead. The reason I dont already know what the enum type is is because the Enums are declared in plugins loaded by PF4J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jorn's comment

> Read the enumclass as a String, then use `Class.forName`

Is what worked for me. The issue with the `ClassNotFoundException` was due to me using PF4J to load plugins. I had to register a list of all the plugin classloaders and use the method `Class.forName(name, true, pluginClassLoader)` to pass the plugin classloaders in manually to find the class.